# What does the "reads" column in sys.dm_exec_sessions actually indicate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dmv

This may seem like a very basic question, and indeed it should be.  However, as a fan of the scientific method, I like to create a hypothesis, then test it to see if I'm correct.  In this case, I'm trying to better understand the output of `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, and more specifically, the single column "reads".

The SQL Server Books Online rather dryly specifies this as:

> Number of reads performed, by requests in this session, during this session. Is not nullable.

One might presume this would indicate the number of *pages* read from disk to satisfy the requests issued by this session since the start of the session.  This is the hypothesis I thought I'd test.

The `logical_reads` column in that same table is defined as:

> Number of logical reads that have been performed on the session. Is not nullable.

From experience using SQL Server, I believe this column reflects the number of pages that have been read both *from disk* and *in memory*.  In other words, the total number of pages *ever* read by the session, no matter where those pages reside.  The differentiator, or value-proposition, of having two separate columns that offer similar information would *seem* to be that one can understand the ratio of pages read from disk (`reads`) vs those read from the buffer cache (`logical_reads`) for a specific session.

On my test rig, I've created a new database, created a single table with a known number of pages of data, then read that table in a new session.  Then I looked at `sys.dm_exec_sessions` to see what the `reads` and `logical_reads` columns said about the session.  At this point I am confounded by the results.  Perhaps someone here can shed some light on this for me.

The test rig:

```
USE master;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.databases d 
    WHERE d.name = 'TestReads')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE TestReads SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE TestReads;
END
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestReads;
GO
ALTER DATABASE TestReads SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
BACKUP DATABASE TestReads TO DISK = 'NUL:'; /* ensure we are in 
                                            simple recovery model */
GO

USE TestReads;
GO

/*
    create a table with 2 rows per page, for easy math!
*/
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestReads
(
    ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_TestReads
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , SomeData CHAR(4000) NOT NULL
);

/*
    insert 5000 pages of data
*/
INSERT INTO dbo.TestReads (SomeData)
SELECT TOP(10000) o1.name
FROM sys.objects o1
    , sys.objects o2
    , sys.objects o3
ORDER BY o1.object_id
    , o2.object_id
    , o3.object_id;


/*
    Verify we have 5,000 pages of data, with 10,000 rows.
*/
SELECT o.name
    , p.rows
    , au.total_pages
    , au.used_pages
    , au.data_pages
FROM sys.partitions p
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON p.object_id = o.object_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units au 
        ON p.hobt_id = au.container_id 
        AND (au.type = 1 or au.type = 0)
WHERE p.index_id = 1
    AND o.name = 'TestReads'
    AND o.type = 'U';

/*
    issue a checkpoint to ensure dirty pages are flushed to disk
*/
CHECKPOINT 30;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL');
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE;
GO

/*
    ensure we have no data cached in memory for the TestReads database
*/
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE TestReads SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE TestReads SET ONLINE;

SELECT DatabaseName = d.name
    , SchemaName = s.name
    , ObjectName = o.name
    , AllocatedMB = COUNT(1) * 8192E0 / 1048576
    , PagesInMemory = COUNT(1)
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors dobd
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units au 
        ON dobd.allocation_unit_id = au.allocation_unit_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p 
        ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id 
             AND (au.type = 1 OR au.type = 0)
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON p.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.databases d 
        ON dobd.database_id = d.database_id
WHERE d.name = 'TestReads'
    AND o.name = 'TestReads'
    AND o.type = 'U'
GROUP BY d.name
    , s.name
    , o.name;
```

The first select statement above shows that in fact the table does consist of 10,000 rows, with 5,025 total pages, 5,020 used pages, and 5,000 data pages; precisely as one would expect:

[image]

The second select statement confirms we have nothing in memory for the `TestReads` table.

In a **new session**, we do the following query, taking note of the session_id:

```
USE TestReads;

SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestReads;
```

As one would expect, this reads the entire table from disk into memory, as shown in the output from `SET STATISTICS IO ON`:

```
(10000 row(s) affected)
Table 'TestReads'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5020, physical reads 3, 
read-ahead reads 4998, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob 
read-ahead reads 0.
```

In a **third** session, we inspect `sys.dm_exec_sessions`:

```
SELECT des.session_id
    , des.reads
    , des.logical_reads
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions des
WHERE des.session_id = 57; /* session_id from the 2nd (previous) session */
```

I'd expect to see `sys.dm_exec_sessions` show *at least* 5,000 for both `reads` and `logical_reads`.  Alas, I see `reads` shows zero.  `logical_reads` does show an expected number of reads somewhere north of 5,000 - it shows 5,020 in my test:

[image]

I know SQL Server read the entire `TestReads` table into memory, by virtue of the `sys_dm_os_buffer_descriptors` DMV:

```
USE TestReads;
GO
SELECT DatabaseName = d.name
    , SchemaName = s.name
    , ObjectName = o.name
    , AllocatedMB = COUNT(1) * 8192E0 / 1048576
    , PagesInMemory = COUNT(1)
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors dobd
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units au 
        ON dobd.allocation_unit_id = au.allocation_unit_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p 
        ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id 
            AND (au.type = 1 OR au.type = 0)
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON p.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.databases d 
        ON dobd.database_id = d.database_id
WHERE d.name = 'TestReads'
    AND o.name = 'TestReads'
    AND o.type = 'U'
GROUP BY d.name
    , s.name
    , o.name;
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 11.0.5343 for this test.

---

Further findings:

If I run the following:

```
SELECT des.session_id
    , des.reads
    , des.logical_reads
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions des
```

I see `reads` of 784 in the session where I'm creating the test rig; however all other sessions show zero in the `reads` column.

I've now updated my SQL Server test instance to 11.0.6020; however the result is the same.

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_requests` will give you nearly same as `set statistics io on` results.

Comment: Interesting `SET STATISTICS IO ON` just before I read from the table in the 2nd session reports 3 physical reads, and 4998 read-ahead reads; however `sys.dm_exec_sessions` still does not reflect that in the `reads` column.

Comment: On 2012 I'm frequently seeing 0 for both reads and logical reads despite non zero results reported from `STATISTICS IO` http://i.stack.imgur.com/XbHae.png

Comment: Interesting, if I run this on SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50.4339) the `reads` column shows 5092 reads.

Comment: Actually I see both columns zero with my approach on all editions I have tested from 2008 to SQL2016CTP3

Comment: thanks for testing this, @MartinSmith - that is very strange!

Comment: But if I don't use SQL cmd mode to connect so the connection hangs around without being automatically disconnected and then look from another session I do see non zero values so maybe just a delay in updating the data structure containing these.

Comment: I'm using multiple sessions from SSMS 2012 against my local machine, in non-SQLCMD mode.  No matter how long I wait, I still see zero reads from the dmv, however `set statistics io on` does show physical reads.

Comment: @MartinSmith and Max: I have also been seeing a delay in some of the increments of the `reads` fields. I suspect it works much like the session_space_usage or whatever DMV that shows tempdb usage per session that doesn't increment until the "request" finishes.

Comment: @srutzky - yes. The addition of a `go` changes things.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/oQyuc.png

Comment: @MartinSmith - I tried your version of the select statement, with the `GO`, etc.  Still zero reads.  I'm thinking maybe there is something with this particular build of 2012.  It's SP2 GDR + 1 security update.  I will update it to the latest build and see.

Comment: Yep. Could be a bug that is fixed between builds.

Comment: An interesting little wrinkle for *writes* http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22953/what-units-are-reads-and-writes-in-dm-exec-query-stats?rq=1#comment42585_22954

Comment: Upgraded to 11.0.6020 (2012 SP3), same result (0 reads).  Even if I restart the instance, do the `select * from dbo.TestReads` then look at `sys.dm_exec_sessions` all sessions have 0 in the `reads` column, whereas `logical_reads` shows expected values.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding has always been that `reads` is only physical (i.e. from disk) and `logical_reads` is only from the Buffer Pool (i.e. from memory). I did a quick test with a smaller table that only has 2 data pages and 3 pages total, and what I am seeing seems to confirm those two definitions.

One thing that is probably giving you bad results is that you are not clearing out the memory. You should run the following between tests to force it to reload from disk:

```sql
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

My test setup was just the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.ReadTest (Col1 CHAR(7500) DEFAULT (' '));
INSERT INTO dbo.ReadTest (Col1) VALUES (DEFAULT), (DEFAULT);
```

I then ran the following:

```sql
SELECT reads, logical_reads FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
SELECT * FROM dbo.ReadTest;
```

(Yes, I was testing in the same session that I was running the DMV in, but that didn't skew the results for the `reads` field, and if nothing else, was at least consistent if it did contribute to the `logical_reads` field.)

For testing I would run the DBCC command and then the two SELECT queries. Then I would see a jump in both the `reads` and `logical_reads` fields. I would run the SELECT queries again and sometimes I would see an additional jump in `reads`.

After that, I would run the two SELECT queries many times and the `reads` would remain the same while the `logical_reads` went up by 4 every single time.

I would then start over with running the DBCC and see that same pattern. I did this quite a few times and the numbers reported were consistent across all of the test runs.

---

More info:

I am also testing on SQL Server 2012, SP2 - 64 bit (11.0.5343).

The following DBCC commands we have both tried and seen no effect:

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL');
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE;
```

Most of the time `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` does work, but I occasionally see that it is still in the Buffer Pool. Odd.

When I:

- `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`: The reads go up by 24 and logical_reads go up by 52.
- Run `SELECT [Col1] FROM dbo.ReadTest;` again: The reads do not go up, but logical_reads go up by 6.
- Add a space to the query text and re-run: The reads do not go up, but the logical_reads go up by 52 (just like right after the `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`).

It would appear that the 52 logical reads accounts for plan generation and the results, which implies that the plan generation caused the additional 46 logical reads. But the physical reads do not go up again and yet it is the same 52 logical reads as it was when it did need to also do the physical reads, hence `logical_reads` does not include the physical `reads`. I am just making this point clear, whether or not it was being stated or implied in the Question.

BUT, one behavior I did notice that throws off (at least a little) using the existence of the table's data pages in `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors`: it gets reloaded by some other process. If you DROPCLEANBUFFERS and check immediately, then it should be gone. But wait a few minutes and it shows up again, but this time without all of the data pages. In my test, the table has 1 IAM page and 4 data pages. All 5 pages are in the buffer pool after I do the `SELECT`. But when it gets reloaded by some other process, it is just the IAM page and 1 data page. I thought it might be SSMS IntelliSense, but I removed all references to that object name in my query tab and it still gets reloaded.

Comment: funnily enough, I removed the `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` (and other `DBCC DROPxxx` commands) from my test rig because they didn't make any difference.  Setting the database offline drops all buffers, and everything else associated with the database.

Comment: I was under the same understanding as you about reads being physical, and logical reads begin from the buffer pool, btw.

Comment: I also tried it with:  `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL');
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE;`

Comment: `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` works for me. `FREEPROCCACHE` and `FREESESSIONCACHE` shouldn't affect this stuff. I had also tried with `FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL')` and found that it had no effect. But `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` did. I say "did" because I am trying again and _now_ it is not working like it did before ;-). I will keep playing. However, I mentioned the definitions of the fields in response to this in the Question: "I believe this column reflects the number of pages that have been read both from disk and in memory".

Comment: @MaxVernon And now I try `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` again and it does clear it from the Buffer Pool. Odd. I will try running the DMV query and `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` in another session.

Comment: Regarding the `logical_reads` column, "I believe this column reflects the number of pages that have been read both from disk and in memory" would really only apply if the session had to read its data from disk into the buffer pool (i.e. some other session had not already read that data into the buffer pool).

Comment: My point is, the `logical_reads` column will never be less than the `reads` column.

Comment: @MaxVernon `logical_reads` does not _truly_ include the `reads`. Most of the time, yes, pages being read from the buffer pool (i.e. logical) need to first be read into the buffer pool (i.e. physical). But, it is not _impossible_ to have higher physical than logical. Run this: `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE reads > logical_reads`. I get 1 row for "SQLAgent - Job invocation engine". But it is just my laptop whereas a production server might have other instances.

Comment: Interesting; I wonder what the logic is behind *that*!

Comment: @MaxVernon Could be the "keep 'em guessin" feature ;-)

Comment: Maybe read ahead reads that were never actually needed by the query?

Comment: @MaxVernon, don't forget to execute a `CHECKPOUNT` in the database context prior to `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`.

Comment: have a +1 for your efforts, Solomon.